# Angular JS - Tree View not recognizing code

Tags: angularjs, treeview

I'm new at Angular JS and I'm having some problems with it. I'm trying to use this module: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview but it's not recognizing the Angular code. You can see my plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xigaA37RieS70CwcK834?p=preview

I wish to know where is the error and I also have a question: if I want to use other modules/plugins and stuff like these, how should I code it? I mean, I would have another .js like:

```
(function(){  
   angular.module('myApp').controller('CONTROLLER_NAME', function($scope){
   ...
   }
}
```

and I should retrieve it on app.js by doing:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview','CONTROLLER_NAME']);
```

Tell me if I missed something..

Thanks in advance,

Lucas.

Comment: your script loading order is incorrect, need to load modules right after angular.js, can't inject something that hasn't been loaded yet. Also using old version of angular in demo

Comment: I changed the order and updated Angular... Still the same problem

Comment: `myApp` should only show up once in `module('myApp')` then when add directive/controolers use `myApp.controler`. Reorganize demo, can use gitHub source for treeview script snd css. Put all the code in one place with script order corrected

Comment: right now you have controller being declared before module...organization is messy

Comment: Alright.. it worked! It was really the order: I just put "main.js" before "tree.js" and the tree showed up. Could you answer my second question? I mean.. actually idk where do I get the dependencies' name from... that angularTreeview comes from (function(l){l.module("angularTreeview",[]) on tree.js?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what is second question?

Comment: if I want to use other modules/plugins and stuff like these, how should I code it? I mean.. actually idk where do I get the dependencies' name from... that angularTreeview comes from (function(l){l.module("angularTreeview",[]) on tree.js?

Comment: you inject all external modules in main page module, `myAp` separated by comma. Then do `myApp.controller('...` for your own